# Mute a Custom Permission within a Permission Set Group

Tags: custom-permission, permission-set-groups

We have a beta release of some new functionality being rolled out and we want to only allow users within the beta to see the new features while at the same time we want to mute the users ability to see the old process. My assumption here was that I could create a "Beta Feature" Permission Set Group providing them with all required permissions for the new feature. Additionally I would add a muted permission set group and mute access to the process we're replacing.

The documentation examples I've seen give me confidence that I can remove users CRUD access to the object record type and fields, but the issue is when I mute the "custom permission" which is used by Flow and Lightning Page Layout to control the visibility of components. Although I have muted the custom permission the user still seems to have access to the old process.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible to mute custom permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I was able initially able to recreate your issue but I was making a mistake. When I opened a case with Salesforce Support and tried to replicate the issue in Production, I was not able to reproduce it. i.e. I successfully muted a custom permission that was controlling the visibility of a Flow Component on a Record Page.

Steps I took:
-Verified a test user did not have this permission given in any other way
-Verified the test user therefore **could not** see the component
-Added the custom permission into a Permission Set Group
-Assigned the Permission Set Group to the test user
-Verified the test user **could** now see the component
-Muted the custom permission in the permission set group
-Verified the test user **could no longer** see the component

Your question *appears* to have a slight misunderstanding of the muting functionality (maybe not, but just to make sure). I found that the only way to mute a permission is if the permission is *only* given to the user in the permission set group but nowhere else. For example: If the user also has a permission on their profile, muting it in the permission set group will have no effect.

Further, for others reading this, `"Muting only impacts group members. Users outside of the group who are assigned to permission sets remain unaffected."`

[Salesforce Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_create_mute.htm&type=5)

Comment: To be clear, the custom permission in question is not assigned to any profile just to the perm set and the two PSGs I mentioned. One PSG has the permission through the perm set and the other has it on the muted perm set. I feel like all examples show it working with object and field permissions but not custom permissions which is where I’m experiencing a problem.

Comment: I tested again and actually got a different result. Muting a Custom Permission worked. I updated my answer. From your comment, if you worded it accurately, it sounds like the problem for you is that you've added the permission in one PSG and muted it in a different PSG. The muting only works for Permissions in the same PSG.

Comment: Appreciate that feedback. I'm not sure I really understand the use case for that functionality. Why would I grant access to a group only to then mute it? At that point seems like I should just not add the permission to the group in the first place. Perhaps you mean that I must add perm set to my group so that I can mute it, BUT it can still be on a separate group? I'll test that because that is what I am trying to achieve, but if that's not the case muting permissions seems useless as a feature. Thanks for your support with this.

Comment: Happy to support! It seems like the purpose is to give similar but slightly restricted permissions to a user without having to create an entirely new permission set. I'm guessing the way Salesforce code is designed it's hard to 'mute' permissions at a larger scope. But if you keep the assignment and the muting to the same 'scope' of a PSG, then they can accomodate it. I bet on the back end they're just transforming the PSG into an what looks to the code like just a normal permission set.